# C# how to access the buttons of Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#

I am using Telerik RadGrid, i add a new button in the grid but how can i write an event for this button (Buy) for example when the user press (Buy) it will add this item to his cart with its price in order to calculate his bill.
regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to listen for the ItemCommand event:

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="Buy" ButtonType="LinkButton" 
    Text="Buy" ConfirmText="Add to cart?" 
    OnItemCommand="rg_ItemCommand" CommandName="AddToBasket" />
```

In your codebehind

```
protected void rg_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "AddToBasket")
    {
        // Add to basket code here
    }
}
```

You may also need to set the `CommandArgument` during the `ItemCreated` or `ItemDatabound` events, or get it using something like `rg.MasterTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.Index]["ItemId"].ToString();` after setting `ClientDataKeyNames="ItemId"` in your MasterTableView settings part in the ascx file (if it is databound).

Comment: it is so easy great man i like these direct answers specialy for begginer(like me) thnx

Comment: My dear, i have tot ask you another question? how can i access other controls like: dropDown List, checkBox o radioButtons??

Comment: Well it depends on where the control is (i.e. in the column, on the RadGrid row?). Submit another question with details about what you want to achieve, submit the URL in these comments and I'll try to get to it :)

Comment: My friend the control is on the RadGrid row example on each row i added a checkBox (i cant checked it i dont know why) and a dropDown List such that each row has its own chackbox and own dropDown list. regards

Comment: You will probably find it much easier to create a new Usercontrol and put everything relating to the RadGrid row inside that. Then, on the ItemDatabound event of your RadGrid, set some property of the Usercontrol that identifies the object or row you are editing (like it's DB primary key or something). There is quite a good example at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/alleditablecolumns/defaultcs.aspx. Also - the Telerik forums are really good if you get stuck. I've had good answers from them in the past. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

When you create the button you'll want to add an OnClick event to it to handle the click on the button. In this event you'll then add the item to the cart. You'll need to parse the parent row of the button to know which item it is.

**Edit:**
Since you are using a GridButtonColumn and not adding a button as you stated then this applies instead (from [Telerik.com](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/radgrid-telerik.webcontrols.gridbuttoncolumn.html)):

> This column renderes a button of the
>   specified ButtonType in each
>   corresponding cell of the items of
>   type [GridDataItem](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/RadGrid~Telerik.WebControls.GridDataItem.html) and
>   [GridEditFormItem](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/RadGrid~Telerik.WebControls.GridEditFormItem.html). You can use this
>   buttons to fire command events that
>   can be handeled in [RadGrid.ItemCommand](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/RadGrid~Telerik.WebControls.RadGrid~ItemCommand_EV.html)
>   event handler. This, in combination
>   with the [event bubbling mechanism](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/grdCommandReference.html) in
>   Telerik RadGrid, allows you to create
>   a column of custom button controls,
>   such as Add, Remove, Select or Edit
>   buttons.

So essentially you'll need to use the grids ItemCommand event to handle the button click.

Comment: man there is no event in GridButtonColumn  <telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="Buy" ButtonType="LinkButton" Text="Buy" ConfirmText="Add to cart?"></telerik:GridButtonColumn>

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ItemCommandEvent of grid. The ItemCommand event is raised when a button is clicked in the Telerik RadGrid control. This allows you to provide an event-handling method that performs a custom routine whenever this event occurs. Follow the [**LINK**](http://www.sitefinity.com/help/developer-manual/radgrid.net2-telerik.webcontrols.radgrid-itemcommand_ev.html) to have more details.